# Which type will return the field method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't work out how to get the Type of a LINQ result. My set contains both strings and bools, so I run into trouble when I try to act on the rows. I attached an incredibly rough workout using try/catch (for a laugh), but it hurts my soul and would much rather know the proper method in obtaining the Type.

```
    private AppointmentInfoClass UpdateDataContext(DataSet phaseDataSet) {

        var phaseCollection = new AppointmentInfoClass();
        var Type = phaseCollection.GetType();
        var properties = Type.GetProperties();

        var result = from DataRow myRow in DataBindings.CompanyAppsDataSet.Tables[0].Rows
                     where (int)myRow["AppointmentID"] == ApptID
                     select myRow;

        var k = 0; 
        foreach (DataRow row in phaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows) {
            string header;

            header = row.Field<string>("Header");

            foreach (var field in result) {     
                try {
                    properties[k].SetValue(phaseCollection, field.Field<string>(header));
                }
                catch (Exception) {

                    properties[k].SetValue(phaseCollection, field.Field<bool>(header).ToString());
                }
            }
            k++;
        }
        return phaseCollection;
    }
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do here? What is `header`? Note that your `result` will be a collection of `DataRow` objects, so enumerating through `result` will not give you fields, but rows.

Comment: Sorry about lack of context, I updated my original post with the full function.

Comment: Just to be sure, you store the name of the DataColumn you want to retrieve (header) into a DataColumn named "Header", and you want to determine the Type of the DataColumn which name is stored in "Header"?

Comment: OK, I see. I would still rename `field` to something like `resultRow` because it's a bit confusing. Have you tried using `field[header]` instead of `field.Field<string>(header)`? That will return you an `object`. I'm still not really sure what this is supposed to do, though.

Comment: Vesan, that's what I was looking for!
Type type = field[header].GetType();

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It will return the type you have written instead of Type

```
string s = field.Field<string>("ColumnName");

bool b = field.Field<bool>("ColumnName");
```